# When is a matrix triangularisable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

When is a matrix triangularisable? I don't seem to find much online regarding the triangularisability of matrices.

What should I look for to prove if a matrix is triangularisable?

What are the implications on its eigenvalues eigenvectors and eigenspaces?

An example a simple triangularisable and one of a non-triangularisable matrix in $\mathbb{R}$ would also help.

Comment: A matrix over a field $k$ is upper triangularizable over $k$ if and only if all of its eigenvalues are in $k$, or equivalently if and only if its characteristic polynomial splits over $k$.

Comment: See "triangularisibility" paragraph in (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_matrix)

Comment: @QiaochuYuan is no field is given, then it's always triangularizable ?

Comment: @Leroy: I don't know what you mean by "no field is given."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Say you have a vector space $V = k^n$ over the field $k$. Then a matrix $A \in k^{n \times n}$ is triangularizable exactly when its characteristic polynomial (or minimal polynomial) splits in $k$ (can be written as a product of linear factors). Equivalently: $A$ has all its eigenvalues in $k$.

If $A$ has all its eigenvalues in $k$, we can put the matrix in Jordan normal form, which is triangular.

Conversely, suppose that $A = (a_{ij})$ is upper triangular. Then the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is

$$ \prod_{j = 1}^n (x - a_{jj}) $$

which is a product of linear factors. You may also note that this implies that $a_{11},\dots,a_{nn}$ are eigenvalues for $A$.

An example of a non-triangularizable matrix over $\mathbf{R}$ is

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$

since its characteristic polynomial, $x^2 + 1$, cannot be written as a product of linear polynomials over $\mathbf{R}$.

Every matrix over $\mathbf{C}$ is triangularizable.

Comment: This result is much easier to prove than the existence of Jordan normal form. It is a straightforward induction: if $T : V \to V$ is a linear operator on a f.d. vector space over $k$ and has all its eigenvalues in $k$, then in particular it has some eigenvector $v_1 \in V$. Now $T : V/v_1 \to V/v_1$ also has some eigenvector $v_2 \in V/v_1$, etc. At the end you have found a basis wrt to which $T$ is triangular.