# Let $A \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$. Which of the following statement(s) is/are true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations, diagonalization

Let $A \in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$. Which of the following statement(s) is/are true?

$(A)$ There exists $B \in M_{n\times n} (\mathbb{C})$ such that $B^2 = A.$

$(B)$ A is diagonalizable

$(C)$ There exists an invertible matrix P such that $P AP^ {−1}$
is upper-triangular.

$(D)$ A has an eigenvalue.

My works : i know that  every real number is  a complex number  so we  xan assume  real as  a complex,...so  option A)  is True

For  $A=\begin{bmatrix}  1 &0 \\ 0& 1\end{bmatrix}$ i take  $B = \begin{bmatrix}  0 &1 \\ 1& 0\end{bmatrix}$

Option B is  not true  take  $A=\begin{bmatrix}  1 &0 \\ 0& 0\end{bmatrix}$

Option  C is  True by definition

option D is also true by definition

Is my answer is correct or not

thanks u

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, statement (A) is not true in general. It is not enough to find a $B$ just for one example of $A$. Here is a counterexample. Take
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \cr 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}.
$$
Assume that $B^2=A$ for some $B$. Then $B$ is nilpotent, since $B^4=A^2=0$. Since $B\in M_2(\Bbb{C})$, we conclude that $B^2=0$. So $A=B^2=0$, a contradiction.

(C) is true, because the characteristic polynomial can be factored into linear factors over $\Bbb{C}$ by the fundamental theorem of algebra. This has been asked and answered at MSE, e.g., here:

[When is a matrix triangularisable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2410401/when-is-a-matrix-triangularisable)

Answer (score 1):

Your answers are not correct.

For A): there does not necessarily exist such a $B$.  For example, there is no matrix $B$ such that $B^2 = A$ when
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&1\\0&0}
$$
Interestingly, there necessarily exists such a $B$ if $A$ is invertible or diagonalizable.

B) Indeed, not every matrix is diagonalizable.  However, the example you chose is a diagonal matrix, which is of course diagonalizable.  The matrix I've written above would work as a counterexample for this option as well.

C) This statement is true.  However, "by definition" is not a valid justification in this case.

D) This statement is true.  Again, I think that "by definition" is insufficient justification.  Ultimately, this fact (in the general case) is a consequence of the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Answer (score 1):

(A) is actually false. For instance, $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ has no square root in $M_{2\times2}(\mathbb{C})$.

(B) is also false, but the matrix that you mentioned *is* diagonalizable. Use the one I mentioned above instead.

(C) That's true, but **not** by definition. You can prove it using (D) and induction.

(D) It's true but, again, **not** by definition. It's a consequence of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra.