# Upper Triangular Matrix Representation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let T ∈ L(V ) with [dim_C V = n < +∞](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9otx.png). Prove that T has an upper-triangular matrix representation with respect to some basis of V.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please see the problem statement image by clicking the blue link above

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you want to show, that for every linear Transformation $f_T:V \to V$ with $V=\mathbb{C}^n$ there is a basis of V such that the transformation matrix T with respect to said matrix is in upper-triangular form.

If that is the case another way to formulate your Problem would be that for $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ there is a Basis B of $\mathbb{C}^n$ such that $^B A ^B$ is in upper-triangular form.

Now one way to approach the problem would be with triangularisability of matrices. Matrices are triangularisable if its characterstical polynomial splits over the respective field of the matrix. In this case the field is $\mathbb{C}$ and $\mathbb{C}$ has the attribute that it is algebraically closed which implies that every polynomial splits into its linear factors. As such every Matrix in $\mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ can be transformed into an (upper) triangular matrix via change of basis.

Also see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2410401/when-is-a-matrix-triangularisable) for further reading.